# Kendo UI Treeview not displaying the data on setDataSource (after loading)

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have a Treeview that loads fine on the page load but i want to filter the tree down to the selected node, the functionality all seems to be working 100%, however it is not displaying anything on the tree when i try to apply the filter even though the json is returning. I hope i am making sense.
Here is my code:

```
<div id="treeview"></div>
<script>
    var selectedId;

    var homogeneous = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/loadtree",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "Id",
                hasChildren: "hasChildren"
            }
        }
    });

    $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
        dataSource: homogeneous,
        dataValueField: "Id",
        dataTextField: "Name",
        select: onSelect

    });



    function onSelect(e) {
        var tv = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView").dataItem(e.node);
        $("#details-container").load("entitydetail/" + tv.Id);
        selectedId = tv.Id;

    }

    function loadTreetoSelected()
    {

        newdata = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/loadtreetoselected/" + selectedId,
                    dataType: "json",
                }

            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "Id",
                    hasChildren: "hasChildren"
                }
            }
        });

        $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView").setDataSource(newdata);    

    }       

</script>

<input type="button" value="Filter to Selected" onclick="javascript: loadTreetoSelected();" />
```

and here is the json that is returned:

```
{"Id":7932,"Name":"OPC 2013","hasChildren":true}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue, but I don't have any problems filtering the data. You just have to compare the JSON returned for loadtree and loadtreetoselected. When you get empty string the treeview goes blank. Please post source code for loadtree and loadtreetoselected action methods. Also JSON string returned for both action methods to help you out. Make sure you don't have javascript errors while calling the method loadTreetoSelected().

Comment: Hi Anil, Thanks i checked the Json again and it was not in an array, i changed my controller to return a list and it sorted out my problem.